# Does regression on nonstationary data always make error term autocorrelated?

Tags: regression, autocorrelation, stationarity

Suppose X and Y are both nonstationary time series, and we regress Y on X and obtain: Y=βX+ϵ. Is it necessary that ϵ be autocorrelated?

If so, may you explain why?

Comment: *Define* $Y = \beta X + \epsilon$ for a random variable $\epsilon.$ Is it necessary that $\epsilon$ be autocorrelated?  Indeed, could you please explain what you mean by "cause autocorrelation" or "autocorrelation problem"?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean, thank you! question edited

Comment: My point is that because $\epsilon$ is completely arbitrary, how could one conclude in general that it must be autocorrelated?